# How to return struct in swift?

Tags: swift, struct

This is my struct:

```
struct State {
  var current: StateEntry?
  var rStack: [StateEntry] = []
  var uStack: [StateEntry] = []
}
```

and i have a func that has return type State:

```
func createEmptyState() -> State {
  var state = State.self
  return  state.current == nil, state.rStack == [], state.uStack == []//How do I return these values of struct in this function?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return null object

`return State()`

To return object containing something.

`return State(current: StateEntry(), rStack: [], uStack: [])`

Answer (score 0):

return State(current: nil, rStack: [], uStack: [])

or

return State.init()

Answer (score 0):

As all properties have default values you can simply return `State()`

```
func createEmptyState() -> State {
    return State()
}
```

- `State.self` is wrong. It represents the type.
- The `return` argument is wrong, too. The syntax doesn't exist.